# Unable to retrieve data from cdrom after ejecting previous cd

Tags: 13.10, cd-ripping

I am currently ripping cdroms, however, I encounter the error message below after ejecting and inserting a new cdrom into the drive:

```
Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
Unhandled error message: Unable to load location
```

At the moment the only way I can rip the new cdrom is to reboot my computer first which isn't ideal.

Does anyone know of a solution to the problem that doesn't involve rebooting my computer every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by typing `cdda://sr0/` directly into the Nautilus address bar which allows me to mount a new cdrom.